# begin_result(): error with argument 3, "w" - Function.w expected an int type, not float

Tags: python, add-on

```
def update_result(engine, width, height, output_file):
    # debug("Reading result %s %d %d" % (output_file, width, height))
    try:
        result = engine.begin_result( 0, 0, width, height)
        lay = result.layers[0]
        lay.load_from_file( output_file)
        engine.end_result( result, cancel=False, do_merge_results=True)
        return True
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        engine.end_result( None, cancel=True, do_merge_results=False)
        pass
    return False

result = engine.begin_result( 0, 0, width, height)
```

here I've got an error like: `"begin_result(): error with argument 3, "w" - Function.w expected an int type, not float"`

```
result = engine.begin_result( 0, 0, width, height)
```

any helps, guys?
It works fine in Blender 3.1.0 alpha but with 3.2.0 it gaves me error

Comment: `int(width), int(height)`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387655/safest-way-to-convert-float-to-integer-in-python

Comment: Thanks. It works fine ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the floats to integers: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

```
int(width), int(height)
```

[Safest way to convert float to integer in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387655/safest-way-to-convert-float-to-integer-in-python)